# Canvas not rendering In reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, canvas

I want to add canvas on the website that i am developing but i can seem to understand why the canvas in not showing up. what could be the issue?

Below is what i have tried. When i hover the mouse on the header it shows that the canvas is updating but not showing anything on the screen

Canvas.jsx

```
export class Canvas extends Component {
  state = {
    container: document.getElementById('test'),
    canvas: document.createElement('canvas'),
    ctx: document.createElement('canvas').getContext("2d"),
    mouseCoords: null,
    particles: [],
    width: 0,
    height: 0,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    document.getElementById('test').appendChild(document.createElement('canvas'));
    this.setState({
      container: document.getElementById('test'),
      canvas: document.createElement('canvas'),
      ctx: document.createElement('canvas').getContext("2d")
    }, () => this.handleResize());
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.handleResize)
  }

  r = (e, t) => {
    return Math.hypot(t[0] - e[0], t[1] - e[1])
  };

  i = (e, t, o, s) => {
    var n = e / s - 1;
    return o * (n * n * (2.2 * n + 1.2) + 1) + t
  };

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
    return null;
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.setState({
      canvas: document.getElementById('test').remove(),
    });
  }


  handleAnimate = () => {
    var e = this.state;
    var that = this;
    if (!(e.width < 800 * window.devicePixelRatio)) {
      var t = e.particles[e.particles.length - 1]
        , o = (e.width - t.coords.ref[0]) / 2
        , s = t.coords.ref[0]
        , n = (e.height - t.coords.ref[1]) / 2
        , a = t.coords.ref[1];
      e.ctx.clearRect(o, n, s, a);
      e.particles.forEach((t) => {
        t.timer += 1;
        const o = Math.max(that.r(t.coords.ref, e.mouseCoords), 150);
          s = t.coords.ref[0] + (e.mouseCoords[0] - t.coords.ref[0]) / (o / e.width * 150);
          n = t.coords.ref[1] + (e.mouseCoords[1] - t.coords.ref[1]) / (o / e.height * 150);
          a = 150 * t.r.ref / o + .5;
        /* eslint-disable */
        s === t.coords.new[0] && n === t.coords.new[1] || (t.coords.old = t.coords.current.slice(), t.coords.new = [s, n], t.r.old = t.r.current, t.r.new = a, t.timer = 1);
        t.timer < 75 && (t.coords.current[0] = that.i(t.timer, t.coords.old[0], t.coords.new[0] - t.coords.old[0], 75),
          t.coords.current[1] = that.i(t.timer, t.coords.old[1], t.coords.new[1] - t.coords.old[1], 75),
          t.r.current = Math.max(that.i(t.timer, t.r.old, t.r.new - t.r.old, 75), 0));
          e.ctx.fillStyle = t.fill;
          e.ctx.beginPath();
          e.ctx.arc(t.coords.current[0], t.coords.current[1], t.r.current, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
          e.ctx.fill()
      });
      this.setState({
        loop: requestAnimationFrame(this.handleAnimate)
      })
    }
  };

  handleHover = (e) => {
    this.state.mouseCoords = [e.clientX * window.devicePixelRatio, e.clientY * window.devicePixelRatio]
  };


  handleResize = () => {
    const {canvas} = this.state;
    var particle = [];
    let newWidth = window.innerWidth * window.devicePixelRatio,
      newHeight = window.innerHeight * window.devicePixelRatio;

    canvas.height = newHeight;
    canvas.width = newWidth;

    this.setState({
      width: window.innerWidth * window.devicePixelRatio,
      height: window.innerHeight * window.devicePixelRatio,
      canvas,
      mouseCoords: [0, newHeight]
    });

    var e = Math.max(newHeight / 21, 40),
      t = Math.floor(newWidth / (e + 5)),
      o = Math.floor(newHeight / (e + 10)) || 90,
      V = [2, 2, 6, 6, 5, 5, 3, 3, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0],
      j = [[2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 3], [1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0], [2, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0], [0, 2, 2, 0, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0], [1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1], [2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0], [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0]];
    console.log(t);


    for (let s = 0; s < o; s += 1) {
      for (var n = 0; n < t; n += 1) {
        var a = Math.round(this.state.width / 2 - e / 2 * (t - 1) + n * e),
          d = Math.round(this.state.height / 2 - e / 2 * (o - 1) + s * e),
          l = "#555555",
          r = e / 20;
        if (s > 0 && s < j.length + 1)
          switch (j[s - 1][t - n - V[s - 1] - 1]) {
            case 0:
              l = "#1DCA7F";
              r = e / 2.5;
              break;
            case 1:
              l = "#047870";
              r = e / 4;
              break;
            case 2:
              l = "#FFFFFF";
              break;
            case 3:
              l = "#6898ae";
              r = e / 2.5
          }
        var i = {
          coords: {
            ref: [a, d],
            current: [a, d],
            new: [a, d],
            old: [a, d]
          },
          r: {
            ref: r,
            current: 0,
            new: r,
            old: 0
          },
          fill: l,
          timer: 1
        };
        particle.push(i);
      }
    }
    this.setState({
      particles: particle
    })
  };

  render() {
    // className="-content-wrapper header"
    return (
      <div className="home">
        <header id="test" onMouseEnter={() => this.handleAnimate()}
                onMouseMove={e => this.handleHover(e)}>
        </header>
      </div>
   )}
}
```

what I want to achieve is a canvas with particles.on hover the particles should move towards where the cursor is headed and zoom the greener particles

Answer (score 3):

You could use refs (note that facebook discourages the uses of refs on most situations, see the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).

I would do something like this:

```
export class Canvas extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.canvas = React.createRef();
    this.context = null // this will be initializaed in componentDidMount()
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d")
  }

  ...

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="home">
        <header id="test" onMouseEnter={() => this.handleAnimate()}
                onMouseMove={e => this.handleHover(e)}>
        </header>
        <canvas ref={this.canvas} className={style.canvas}/>
        <!-- Make sure to size the canvas correctly using CSS -->
      </div>  
  )}
}
```